# CUPS - how to create users to control the access to CUPS printers?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, printing, cups, ipp

I have set up my printer on CUPS ubuntu, and it can be use via ipp. I haven't config the users yet, but I heard that we can pass username and password via ipp url like this: `http://username:password@server:631/printers/MyPrinter`

For example, John use `http://john:password@server:631/printers/MyPrinter` to access the printer. And I can login into the cups using root/admin user, and set John enable or disable to use the printer.

Can we make this work? And how to make this work?

Hope you understand my poor english...

Answer (score 1):

As you're running Ubuntu use one of the following depending on what you want to achieve:

1. If you want John to be able to print to a certain printer **or not**, just go to <kbd>System Settings</kbd> → <kbd>Printers</kbd> and then click <kbd>Access Control</kbd> and deny printing for everyone except John:

   [image: Printer Properties - Access Control]

   Use `Allow printing` if there would be less users to deny access to the printer instead.
2. If you want John to control *all of the printer queues on that machine* and put jobs on hold, change their priority, ... just add him to the `l`ine `p`printer `admin` group like this:

   ```
   sudo usermod --append --groups lpadmin John
   ```

Comment: If that is not what you're trying to achieve, leave a comment and I'll delete my answer.